# How to move a file for which a "permission denied " popup appears

Tags: vba

There is a file I'm trying to move using VBA which shows "permission denied" when copied/moved from one path to another.

Note: the file is in the `c:\program files` folder.

1. When used FileSystemObject:

   I am unable to move it to destination folder because the "permission denied" popup is not overriden
2. When I use shell object

   To move the file using CMD prompt, it doesn't allow me to perform the move action and displays "incorrect syntax" error

Comment: Show the exact code you use and the exact error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try removing the "read-only" attribute to the file by doing so :

```
Dim FileToMove As String 

If Len(Dir$(FileToMove)) > 0 Then

     SetAttr FileToMove, vbNormal 'This will probably allow you to modify the path of the file 
End If
```